# Huge texture management in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, mipmaps

I have developped a big map where the user can navigate. Let's say this map has a resolution of 15000x5000 (for example. It can be even higher). The way I am handling this in 2D is with a Tile Map (tech used by GoogleMaps or OpenStreetMap): split the image in small tiles, and create different tiles according to the zoom level.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map

My question now is, **how to do something similar but projecting that image onto a 3D mesh instead** (using OpenGL)?

My guess is that I would have to split the mesh in UV tiles, every frame check the camera-tile distance, and select a different texture for that tile. I have been reading about array textures, mipmapping....but none of it seems to fit in my application.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what part of this you need help with. You describe several pieces: 1) split the map texture into tiles, 2) split the mesh into tiles, 3) calculate camera distance to tiles, 4) select texture per tile using distance. Which of these steps is giving you trouble, and what exactly is that trouble?

Comment: I am not sure whether this would be the proper way to tackle this task. 
Will I be able to load all the tiles into the GPU? How do I split the mesh into tiles?  How to select texture per tile using distance? Do I need to generate mipmaps for every texture or does OpenGL take care of that for me?

I have some background with OpenGL, but not for shaders and texture management

Comment: What happened when you tried simply loading the big map? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's more than one question. StackExchange works on a 1 question per post model, so try editing your post to focus on just the first part you need help with. Many games handle large terrains by splitting them into chunks this way. They don't store every full-res tile in memory at the same time, just the ones needed for what the camera can see in its current position, and more distant tiles may be down-graded to a lower resolution to reduce load. If you search for "terrain LOD (level of detail)" you may find existing resources about these strategies, and use that research to refine your post.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into terrain LOD techniques to find the strategies used